# Make Json Object with properties coming from array of objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, typescript

I have an array of objects

```
  [
   {"key": "key1", "value" : true },
   {"key": "key2.subKey1", "value" : true },
   {"key": "key2.subKey2", "value" : true },
  ]
```

How would I get an object that takes the parameters from the key strings and makes something like this in typescript?

```
{
 "key1" : true,
 "key2" : {
   "subkey1" : true,
   "subkey2" : true
  }
}
```

I know you can add a value using the (dot). but how do I use a string that contains everything and do it? because specially in typescript you can't I think ( I'm new in Typescript)

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVK8Gm) what you're looking for?  Are you trying to get this to work at the *type level* (i.e., the compiler knows exactly the type of the output) as well as the *value level* (i.e., the object you get at runtime)?  They are basically two separate issues; the former requires TypeScript type manipulation with template literal types; the latter can be done in pure JavaScript. Do you have other use cases you can test?  I'm happy to write up an answer but I'm not sure I understand the extents of the question well enough.

Comment: Hi! So basically I do start from the JSON file, which is made like the one in the question, and from that the "path" you could say, gets saved in an object so that can be saved in a db. now the issue is getting the data from the db and reconstructing the initial JSON file. I am not really concerned about the type, since it is declared as a Record<string, unknown>, so even if a value of key is an object it is fine

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So you want a function `dottedKVsToObj()` that takes an array of `KV` objects, defined as

```
interface KV {
    key: string, // <-- dotted path
    value: any
}
```

and returns a single object whose structure corresponds to putting the `value` property at the path represented by the dotted path string `key`.

---

If you don't care about the output type of this function (aside from something very wide like `Record<string, unknown>`), one way to write it is like this:

```
function dottedKVsToObj(kvs: readonly KV[]) {
    const ret: Record<string, unknown> = {}
    for (const { key, value } of kvs) {
        let cur: any = ret;
        const path = key.split(".");
        const lastKey = path.pop()!;
        for (const k of path) {
            if (!(k in cur)) cur[k] = {};
            cur = cur[k];
        }
        cur[lastKey] = value;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You could probably do this via functional programming techniques instead of explicit loops, but I find it easier to think about this way.  For each `key`/`value` pair in the `kvs` input, we [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `key` into an array of path elements `path`.  This will always have at least one element in it, so we [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the last one off the array to use as the final key which will get the `value`.  Then, we take our return object `ret` and start going down into properties and subproperties based on the path elements in `path`.  If we don't already have an object there, we initialize it with an empty object.

You can verify that this works for the example input in question:

```
const kvs = [
    { "key": "key1", "value": true },
    { "key": "key2.subKey1", "value": true },
    { "key": "key2.subKey2", "value": true },
];
    
const obj = dottedKVsToObj(kvs);
console.log(obj)
/* {
  "key1": true,
  "key2": {
    "subKey1": true,
    "subKey2": true
  }
} */
```

---

If you do care about the output type of the function, you could use the same implementation, but give the call signature a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type that uses a recursive type involving [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to split the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) path types at each dot character and build up an object type corresponding to the output object.  It's a lot more fragile and complicated than the implementation, and there are probably a bunch of edge cases.

For fun, here's one way to do it:

```
type Prefix<T> = T extends `${infer A}.${infer R}` ? A : T;

type RemoveKeyPrefix<T extends KV> =
    T extends { key: `${infer A}.${infer R}`, value: infer V } ? { key: R, value: V } : never;

type DottedKVsToObj<T extends { key: string, value: any }> = { [E in T as Prefix<E['key']>]:
    RemoveKeyPrefix<E> extends infer F ?
    [F] extends [never] ? E['value'] : DottedKVsToObj<Extract<F, KV>> : never
} extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

declare function dottedKVsToObj<T extends KV>(kvs: readonly T[]): DottedKVsToObj<T>;
```

So the function `dottedKVsToObj` take an array of `T` objects constrained to `KV`, and returns an object of type `DottedKVsToObj<T>`, which is defined in terms of itself.  I'm not going to go into detail about how it works here, although anything in particular can be answered upon request.

Let's see how it works:

```
const kvs = [
    { "key": "key1", "value": true },
    { "key": "key2.subKey1", "value": true },
    { "key": "key2.subKey2", "value": true },
] as const;
    
const obj = dottedKVsToObj(kvs);
/* const obj: {
    key1: true;
    key2: {
        subKey1: true;
        subKey2: true;
    };
} */
```

Looks good.  The inferred type of `obj` matches the actual value returned by the implementation.  Note that the definition of `kvs` needed a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so that the compiler would not widen the keys like `"key2.subKey1"` to `string`... if that had happened the best you could get would be `Record<string, boolean>`, which is not really worth the effort.

Anyway since you don't really care about this, I won't worry about edge cases, and detailed explanations, or optimizing how one might call it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gNwjAvDA2gKBjmBvGAIjgFMBPQgLiNLIEZCAaIhAQwBsBXEqmKAJ24wAvo2y4CxcrylkATADoInAEYBpcg2aE2XHtQFDR4nJNozai5evJymLDt16GSIsQF0YrZKEhQA3JhBvtAwICoAVqgwACYgUFAkMWoAahAAKiAA8pEAFIgQAJSBAPQAVDAhsOER1Hgm8JoGgiSBuI3ydQ3t1hr0zdxt7bi9tgOtDcKBwjBlJcHgECDsJArsIADmuTWFmOX44rIM42I4snZd7YSj9M4tp7jXqn0XfC3iwpgzc0F7Jf8AwFA4EgwG-cEQgCWYES-AAZqxgK5Ugd2rRqNB+NCNg8cLpuNRWGAyF8glAyAAHVwABX4JDhkIAHgAedIAPmi6RgJEZiTAMWQAAMACR4aFwkj8GAAQWEClF4slMAASsJBTAAPwymDUdKBTDkqkqkgAWxACBIfVp9KZrO5vJI-OQqQ5KAaXJ5fIF+A61BFYrAEqlsvlAaDKrVzHxJGoiqlKREmp96JVUccMZgCZm1DAJAt-H1htcABF4olkmlMjkInbPY7vQQU5jsWm9ITiSJXT70ABRGDQmBc7wwa0Mlk99AAclok-cbPclAaytN5st5FHtp7HLrTv7gaVADFNQ10AfPDvvehc-nPFqJ5Po7OdTBSwkkqkMtlIsye7z+IioGZA9mBdDkczzSUvntL1kDjGAsiTAh0DUPcOhAOF4IXeDkM8bMYGvSV9ThTgwGAKBIXAWIy3fSsvxrD0HV3F18iQag6VYOIwHYMhB3QdxCmoV9yw-Ktv3ZQJiNI8jKLiN8K0-asWIgNiSA48BuJgVI+MKVFcCqGA6Sgahl1AfgYmZZswBxGASLgMAQAAdzALs8E+do4RAKVcn0xtyFbIwwgwgodPqYZcBWWBgE4fh2x4tBDKGML9IpVgoAAC2iWglApdhISgXJCAUQhim6PTFlgdhvCgPpohS9KFApEAKVyQoAEJEuGDyvP0uBApgOq0pC0qwshDDcla-JUKi-hCh06b0DgTw0FcjqwpwabonmxbVtwNy1vmyroD6JaYGjDq9pwQzorAAySACUlMCAA)